# OpenLayers delete selected features by the right-click pop-up

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Following this question:

[Deleting selected feature in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413123/deleting-selected-feature-in-openlayers)

I would like to have also an option to delete the object by the mouse right-click.

I found an option for switching on the context menu:

[How can I select a feature in Openlayers 3 by right click it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148428/how-can-i-select-a-feature-in-openlayers-3-by-right-click-it)

and tried to combine it with my example by using this code

https://rawgit.com/jonataswalker/ol-contextmenu/master/examples/contextmenu.js

in order to have some small popup after right-click on the selected object with the delete option.

Finally I've built the code like this:

```
var deleteFeature = function(evt){
  var rightcl = document.getElementById('map').oncontextmenu = function(e){
  e = e?e:window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // For non-IE browsers.
  else return false; // For IE browsers.
  };
  if(evt.keyCode == 46){
  var selectCollection = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
    if (selectCollection.getLength() > 0) {
    vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectCollection.item(0));
   }
 } else if (rightcl) {
  var selectCollection = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
    if (selectCollection.getLength() > 0) {
    vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectCollection.item(0));
   }
 };
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

which doesn't work at all.

I tried to define the right-click event by using this example:

http://spatialnotes.blogspot.com/2010/11/capturing-right-click-events-in.html

and include it as an internal variable. In this case, the right-click would work normally for the whole map, but it could run the pop-up or simply delete the selected feature.

Is there any chance to resolve it?

My full JSfiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8grsq5hk/

Comment: Which version of OL are you using?

Comment: OL 5 I guess. When I export the map from QGIS2web all the files are dated 14.10.2020.

Comment: You can get the exact version with this code: `var version;
    try {
        var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ style: new ol.style.Circle({ radius: 30 }) });
    }
    catch(err) {
        var parts = err.message.split("/v");
        parts = parts[parts.length - 1].split("/");
        version = parts[0];
        console.log('OL version: ' + version);
    }`

Comment: How to include it into my code?

Comment: You can put ti anywhere where it will be executed and then check browser debugger console upon execution.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Right-click behaves as normal.

Comment: This code is only to display OL version in browser debugger console. Please look in the console what OL version are you using.

Comment: Right, I see. I have version 6.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you are setting right click processing inside the event listener `deleteFeature`, so it's set up only after delete is pressed. You should catch right click outside `deleteFeature` event listener, on the same global level.

Code could then look something like this:

```
function removeSelectedFeature() {
  var selectCollection = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
  if (selectCollection.getLength() > 0) {
    vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectCollection.item(0));
  }
}

var deleteFeature = function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 46) {
    removeSelectedFeature();
  }
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);

document.getElementById('map').oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  removeSelectedFeature();
  e = e ? e : window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  else {
    return false;
  }
};
```